# How to keep content from bunching up in a transistion div?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to make use of the transition css rule but my problem is all the content inside the div is bunched together when the transition is idle and not being moused over. Once you mouse over the content in the div, or the title in my example, is stretched out to full form.

Is there a way to make the title stretch out on one line the way it should look while the box is not being moused over?

Here is a jsfiddle of an example of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/3W2hC/

```
.title { 
    width:420px;
    text-align:center;
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I was able to do this. By adding a width. However, there is now a scroll bar. How do i go about removing the scroll bar?

Comment: You miscopied your link.

Comment: Thanks yeah re posted link. Now i got it to be full form but there are scroll bars. know how to remove them by chance?

Comment: I'm sorry could you be more specific?  Do you want the title to always be on one line and fully visible? do you want the box to hide the end of the title? (`overflow:hidden`) Do you want it to wrap to two lines?

Comment: (overflow:hidden)  did the job. Thanks!

Comment: No problem ;) - I'm going to be cheesey and write this as an answer, I hope you will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content to be cut off inside of the div, just give your div `overflow:hidden` in your css.

In your case it will be:

```
#main {
    overflow:hidden;
    ...
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3W2hC/1/